# Sitecore/Dynamics integration user missing in marketing list

Tags: sitecore, microsoft-dynamics

We have Sitecore linked to Dynamics using the [Sitecore integration module](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Dynamics%20CRM%20Campaign%20Integration/DCRMCI20.aspx). Within Dymanics we have a marketing list that contains 1000 users and we have successfully added this list as a role to Sitecore.

However when we look at the number of members in the role within Sitecore  only 800 of them are showing. Somewhere between dynamics and Sitecore 200 users are going missing. Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 0):

The provider:

Only shows the active marketing lists from CRM

Only shows the marketing lists with the **Contact** member type.

The provider only shows Contacts entities; it shows neither **accounts** nor **leads** from CRM.

Answer (score 0):

I have found there are a lot of issues with caching in the Sitecore CRM module.

I don't know if this has anything to do with your specific issue but I am seeing similar behaviour. For example, if I add a marketing list in Dynamics and view the associated users in that role in Sitecore everything is fine but if I were to go ahead and add new contacts to the marketing list in Dynamics then those new users are not reflected in Sitecore until the cache is cleared (My guess is the IsUserInRoleCache).

I think this is a pretty bad flaw since regular marketing users will probably not know to clear the cache or forget even if they have a way of doing so.

What's even worse is that the same situation occurs when working with users in Sitecore. The profile details for a user are not updated until the cache is cleared (UserProfileCache). I found that this can actually lead to data being overwriten in Dynamics when the two-way (Read-Write) connection is enabled between Sitecore and Dynamics. For example, old data may be displayed for a user in Sitecore if the cache was not cleared and then the old data is sent back to Dynamics on save which overwrites the correct data stored in the CRM. I ended up writing some custom code to get around this issue because I did not feel comfortable moving forward with this issue in place.

Hope this helps even if it's not exactly the cause of your issue.